# How do you tell if a symbol in System.map is a variable or a function?

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm trying to find a way to differentiate the symbols in the System.map file. Symbols can be functions or variables but that's the furthest I got. I checked the symbol types, but they didn't help.

Comment: 1. Get kernel sources. 2. Find that symbol definition in kernel sources. 3. Inspect if it's a function or a variable.

Comment: That would be a bit hard to do for all of them, but yes, it would work for a couple.

Comment: Why didn't the symbol types help? The symbol types are documented in the man page for "nm".

Comment: Yes, but if it only says for the t/T symbol:  "The symbol is in the text (code) section." And kind of the same for other symbols so it's not too helpful for me.